# Quicker way of converting from string with European date format to ISO dateformat

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datetime

I wanted to ask if there is a quicker way of doing this:

```
CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), CONVERT(date, '18.02.2016', 104), 112)
```

The following produces an error:

```
CONVERT(date, '18.02.2016', 112)
```

*The entered string isn't style 112*

SQL Server 2012 is used.

Comment: Tag dbms used. (CONVERT is a product specific function.)

Comment: You are using MS SQL-Server?

Comment: A date should be stored as a `DATE`, not as a string, then applying a specific format is only for casting to/from a string. So for casting this string to a date simply use: `CONVERT(date, '18.02.2016', 104)`

Comment: What do you mean by "quicker"? Do you mean quicker performing or quicker to write??

Comment: The first expression is the correct method, you could consider using char(10) instead, but there is no better way to get the char format. I would stick to the date format though - CONVERT(date, '18.02.2016', 104)

Comment: I agree with this sentiment, the problem is the third party solution doesnt let you define database fields.

Comment: I once worked with a third party db that stored dates and times as strings.  To avoid constantly rewriting the same convert statements we applied a series of views on top the raw tables.

Answer (score 2):

The first expression is the correct method, you could consider using char(10) instead.

This alternative method using [FORMAT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(FORMAT_TSQL);k(SQL11.SWB.TSQLRESULTS.F1);k(SQL11.SWB.TSQLQUERY.F1);k(MISCELLANEOUSFILESPROJECT);k(DevLang-TSQL)&rd=true) will be more flexible allowing other than the standard formats. FORMAT was introduced in sqlserver 2012.

```
SELECT FORMAT(CONVERT(date, '18.02.2016', 104), 'yyyyMMdd')
```

Answer (score 0):

With this:

```
set dateformat dmy
select CONVERT(datetime, '18.02.2016')
```

the result is:

```
2016-02-18 00:00:00.000
```

So:

```
set dateformat dmy
select CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CONVERT(datetime, '18.02.2016'), 112)
```

result is:

```
20160218
```